# События по геопозиционированию

Tags: android, геолокация

Подскажите оптимальную архитектуру для приложения:
Нужно приложение, работающее в фоне, которое бы по геопозиции отрабатывало бы действия - вызывало уведомления, запускало файлы и т.п.
Как это реализовать с учетом экономии, чтобы приложение не выедала батарею устройства с бешеной скоростью?

Comment: Возможно вы найдете решение в службах (Service)

Comment: Так и сделал, запущен сервис, который следит за координатами и "будит" при необходимости активность. Но батарея расходуется очень быстро

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экономия ресурса батарейки это всегда компромисс.
Для начала представите себе модель поведения пользователя. Что значит, что он в этой геопозиции? Для меня это ответ такой то что пользователь находится в данной точке не менее x минут и не более y метров. Тут надо определиться с х чем больше интервалы запроса, тем лучше для батарейки. Например если пользователь проехал на машине мимо этого места, то значит что он там не был и или был? 
Во вторых не обязательно запрашивать каждый раз позицию у датчика. По мимо вас за пользователем могут следить и другие программы, например тот же Google. Можно запрашивать у системы последние координаты, и уже смотреть не слишком ли они старые.
В третьих  неплохо предугадывать движение, например если рядом в 100 километрах нет не одной действующей точки то наверно и не стоит вызывать локатор, каждые пару минут.
Еще можно анализировать куда пользователь движется и пытаться угадать, и взаимозависимости от этого корректировать таймеры.

В целом чтоб экономить батарейку рецепт один, как можно реже запрашивать данные непосредственно у датчика